# How to deal with Chrome alerts with Selenium (Python)

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation

I am very new to Selenium and am trying to automate sending messages through WhatsApp Web through Google Chrome. I am using a different api which lets users write messages directly to the phone number specified: https://wa.me/. However, there is an alert box which pops up and my code is unable to accept it.
[Alert box screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m4f1s.jpg)
I have tried 
`driver.switch_to_alert().accept()`

 but this is resulted in a deprecation warning, so switched to:

```
alert_box = driver.switch_to.alert
alert_box.accept()
```

Both result in the following error:

```
Exception has occurred: NoAlertPresentException
Message: no such alert
  (Session info: chrome=105.0.5195.102)
  File "<hidden>", line 30, in <module>
    driver.switch_to.alert.accept()
```

Current code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

# Ensure you are logged in to whatsapp web
num = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" # hid the number
driver.get("https://wa.me/" + num)

# Allow time to load page
driver.implicitly_wait(3)

# Switch to alert window to accept the alert to open URL
driver.switch_to.alert.accept()

driver.find_element(By.XPATH, './/a[@class="_9vcv _advm _9scb"][@id="action-button"][@title="Share on WhatsApp"]').click()

# Switch to alert window to accept the alert to open URL
driver.switch_to_alert().accept()

driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="fallback_block"]/div/div/h4[2]/a').click()
```

Interestingly, no alert shows up if I manually go through the screens myself.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably should add some code to wait for the alert to open.
Have a look a the following snipped.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

try:
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    wait.until(EC.alert_is_present(), 'waiting for alert')
    alert = driver.switch_to.alert
    alert.accept()
except TimeoutException:
    print("timed out waiting for alert")
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however, the TimeOutException is caught each time suggesting no alert was detected. 
The exception is caught at the ```wait.until(EC.alert_is_present(). 'waiting for alert')``` line

Comment: Strange. Do you see an alert? Please you post your complete example.

Comment: Hi @doberkofler, it wasn't working for some reason when I was using the ```driver.get("https://wa.me/" + num)```. However, I realised that just using the whatsapp link ```driver.get("https://web.whatsapp.com/send?phone="+num``` works. While the new link does not throw the same alert as in the question, it does throw an alert and it is handled perfectly by your code.